# Google maps how to calculate south west and north east bound for overlay

Tags: google-maps

While displaying an overlay over google maps using the API. I am googling for last three days how to calculate the South West and North east bounds for an overlay of size 100X100. I found millions of examples but the bounds were written hard coded.

My input is Center Latitude and Longitude and a 100x100 image.

The code I found is:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {lat: 62.323907, lng: -150.109291},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(SE),
      new google.maps.LatLng(NE));

  // The photograph is courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey.
  var srcImage = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/';
  srcImage += 'examples/full/images/talkeetna.png';

  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
}
```

I am woundering how these bounds were calculated?

```
 SE and NE
```

Comment: What does your overlay look like?  The bounds calculated for a 100x100 pixel square will depend on the zoom level the image is targeted at (unless you have different images for each zoom).  What bounds level is the 100x100 image targeted at?

Comment: waht is  bounds level @geocodezip?

Comment: Sorry, typo, meant zoom level.

Comment: Related question: [How to calculate bounds in google map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274816/how-to-calculate-bounds-in-google-map)

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the bounds (specifically a [`google.maps.LatLngBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) object) that is 100px x 100px centered at the center of the bounds of that overlay:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(62.281819, -150.287132),
  new google.maps.LatLng(62.400471, -150.005608));
```

1. find the pixel position of the center:

```
var center = bounds.getCenter();
var centerPt = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(center);
```

2. find the pixel point 50px up and 50px right of it

```
var topRightPt = new google.maps.Point(centerPt.x+50, centerPt.y+50);
```

3. find the pixel point 50px down and 50px left of it

```
var botLeftPt = new google.maps.Point(centerPt.x-50, centerPt.y-50);
```

4. translate those back to latitude and longitude coordinates

```
  var sw = overlay.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(botLeftPt);
  var ne = overlay.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(topRightPt);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rwsqcgv0/2/)

```
overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
google.maps.event.addListener(overlay, 'projection_changed', function() {
  var centerPt = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(center);
  var topRightPt = new google.maps.Point(centerPt.x+50, centerPt.y+50);
  var botLeftPt = new google.maps.Point(centerPt.x-50, centerPt.y-50);
  var sw = overlay.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(botLeftPt);
  var ne = overlay.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(topRightPt);
  var overlayBnds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw,ne);
  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
     map: map,
     bounds: overlayBnds
  })
});
```

**code snippet:**

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
// This example creates a custom overlay called USGSOverlay, containing
// a U.S. Geological Survey (USGS) image of the relevant area on the map.

// Set the custom overlay object's prototype to a new instance
// of OverlayView. In effect, this will subclass the overlay class therefore
// it's simpler to load the API synchronously, using
// google.maps.event.addDomListener().
// Note that we set the prototype to an instance, rather than the
// parent class itself, because we do not wish to modify the parent class.

var overlay;
USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// Initialize the map and the custom overlay.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {
      lat: 62.323907,
      lng: -150.109291
    },
    mapTypeId: 'satellite'
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(62.281819, -150.287132),
    new google.maps.LatLng(62.400471, -150.005608));
  var center = bounds.getCenter();

  // The photograph is courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey.
  var srcImage = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/' +
    'javascript/examples/full/images/talkeetna.png';

  // The custom USGSOverlay object contains the USGS image,
  // the bounds of the image, and a reference to the map.
  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(overlay, 'projection_changed', function() {
    var centerPt = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(center);
    var topRightPt = new google.maps.Point(centerPt.x + 50, centerPt.y + 50);
    var botLeftPt = new google.maps.Point(centerPt.x - 50, centerPt.y - 50);
    var sw = overlay.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(botLeftPt);
    var ne = overlay.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(topRightPt);
    var overlayBnds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
    var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      map: map,
      bounds: overlayBnds
    })


  });
}

/** @constructor */
function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

  // Initialize all properties.
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;

  // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
  // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
  // method so we'll leave it null for now.
  this.div_ = null;

  // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
  this.setMap(map);
}

/**
 * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
 * added to the map.
 */
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';

  // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(img);

  this.div_ = div;

  // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};

USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

  // We use the south-west and north-east
  // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
  // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

  // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
  // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
  // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

  // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};

// The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
// we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: My core question is how to calculate the bounds. Here you are using bounds to find center

Comment: bunds are unknown things. I want to calculate that

Comment: The known values are the center and the height and width.  How I got the center value I used in the calculation isn't relevant to the answer, pick an arbitrary center if you like.